# basic coffeescript find if in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, coffeescript

In coffee script I'm trying to figure out if something is included in an array or not.  But can't seem to figure out the correct syntax.  Is there not a way to do this without have to iterate over them?

Thanks,

```
  if $(this).val() is in ["needs_cover","comatose"]
    $("#head_count").hide()
  else
    $("#head_count").show()
```

Comment: `$(this).val() in ["needs_cover", "comatose"]` should work.

Comment: I knew I was close thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just drop the `is`:

```
if $(this).val() in ["needs_cover","comatose"]
    $("#head_count").hide()
  else
    $("#head_count").show()
```

That would translate to the following JavaScript:

```
var _ref;

if ((_ref = $(this).val()) === "needs_cover" || _ref === "comatose") {
  $("#head_count").hide();
} else {
  $("#head_count").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common use case, you could write a function, which would also allow you to write a routine that is a bit more compact as well, like so:

```
hideShowFn = (valSelector, hideShowElSelector, compareArr) ->
    if $(valSelector).val() in compareArr then return $(hideShowElSelector).hide()
    $(hideShowElSelector).show()
```

I prefer doing the above as it flattens the code a little bit. This is my preference.

You would call the function like so:

```
hideShowFn this, '#head_count', ['needs_cover', 'comatose']
```